# Use partial match to set category in Excel

Tags: excel

I have exported my bank statement as a csv. In the Description column it shows things like "SPROUTS FARMERS MKT#28 PRESCOTT VALL  AZ" (where I buy my food) and "ARCO 428810 AMPM PRESCOTT AZ" where I usually buy gas.

I would like to search for a partial match on "SPROUTS" and label those rows as FOOD in the category column. Likewise, a search for "ARCO" and label those rows as AUTO EXPENSE in the category column.

Running several of these kinds of searches would result in most of my expenses being categorized. The rest I'll do by hand.

I think VLOOKUP might be useful here, but can't figure out how I would use it to add the label in the category column.

Appreciate any help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assume your data starts from `A2` cell then put following formula to `B2` cell.

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("SPROUTS",A2)),"FOOD",IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("ARCO",A2)),"AUTO EXPENSE","--"))
```

***Screenshot:***
[image]

Comment: Thanks, Harun! I hadn't considered using multiple IF statements like this. Brilliant!

Comment: If you found the answer useful, then please accept (tick it as green) my answer so that other visitor can see it is a useful answer. Thanks.